# Un-nesting nested tuples to single terms

Tags: nested, tuples, apache-pig, flatten, udf

I have written an udf (`extends EvalFunc<Tuple>`) which has as output tuples with inner tuples (nested).

For example the dump looks like:

```
(((photo,photos,photo)))
(((wedg,wedge),(audusd,audusd)))
(((quantum,quantum),(mind,mind)))
(((cassi,cassie),(cancion,canciones)))
(((calda,caldas),(nova,novas),(rodada,rodada)))
(((fingerprint,fingerprint),(craft,craft),(easter,easter)))
```

Now I want to process each of this terms, distinct it and give it an id (`RANK`). To do this, i need to get rid of the brackets. A simple `FLATTEN`does not help in this case.

The final output should be like:

```
1 photo
2 photos
3 wedg
4 wedge
5 audusd
6 quantum
7 mind
....
```

My code (not the udf part and not the raw parsing):

```
tags = FOREACH raw GENERATE FLATTEN(tags) AS tag;
tags_distinct = DISTINCT tags;
tags_sorted = RANK tags_distinct BY tag;
DUMP tags_sorted;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your UDF is return is not optimal for your workflow. Instead of returning a tuple with variable number of fields (which are tuples), it would be a lot more convenient to return a bag of tuples.

Instead of

```
(((wedg,wedge),(audusd,audusd)))
```

you will have

```
({(wedg,wedge),(audusd,audusd)})
```

and you will be able to FLATTEN that bag to:
1. make the DISTINCT
2. RANK the tags

To do so, update your UDF like this :

```
class MyUDF extends EvalFunc <DataBag> {

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        // create DataBag
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. how do i specify the data type? "xyz AS tag:bag{t:tuple()};" - like this?

Comment: Yeah thanks, but I already did that change in my UDF. I mean the data type in pig. To tell pig its an bag with tuple and so that i can iterate over it. My problem is that i couldnt figure out how to iterate over it, until yet

Comment: If you're not able to dump your data to the format, ({(f1, f2), (f1, f2)}), you will need a UDF to parse your input.

Comment: The problem is i need to specify the data schema. I thought it is "b:bag{t:Tuple()}" but this dont work